# jquery datepicker changeMonth dropdown width in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datepicker

```
<input type="text" id="txtDateTo1" size="7">

$('#myDatePicker').datepicker({changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, yearRange: '2010:2013'});
```

My input box is contained in a DIV that is absolutely positioned.

In IE8, the month and year dropdowns are excessivly wide.  In chrome it looks just fine.

How can i force the two dropdowns to the correct width?  Or even just set the pixels as fixed.

[image]

---

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add your specific width to these two CSS classes.

```
select.ui-datepicker-month

select.ui-datepicker-year
```

Comment: In my css i added select.ui-datepicker-month{width:500px;}   , however nothing has changed... even in chrome.  500,1000, 20, no difference.

Comment: What about select.ui-datepicker-month{width:500px !important;} ?